# How to get the Count of the Child nodes based on node value?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a following xml.

```
<Result>
    <Message>
      <Type>Error</Type>
      <Description>ABC</Description>
    </Message>
    <Message>
      <Type>Warning</Type>
      <Description>DEF</Description>
    </Message>
    <Message>
      <Type>Error</Type>
      <Description>GHI</Description>
    </Message>
    <Message>
      <Type>Information</Type>
      <Description>IJK</Description>
    </Message>
</Result>
```

I want the Result like

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL

Total Error: 2
Total warning: 1
Total Information:1
```

I could able to get the total number of child records using count(//Message/Type), its resulting 4.

I wants to get the total number of errors, I tried

count(//Message/Type &eq; "Error")

but its not worked.

Here is my xsl.

```
    <ul>
      <xsl:for-each select="Message">
        <li>
          <xsl:value-of select="./Type" />
        </li>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
    Total Count Error:<xsl:value-of select="(count(//Error/Type &eq; "Error"))"/>
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start, if you want to output the description of each **Message** element, you need to reference the **Description** element, and not **Type**

```
  <xsl:for-each select="Message">
    <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="Description" />
    </li>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

In terms of adding up the total Errors, the expression would be as follows (assuming you were positioned on the parent **Result** element.

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(Message[Type = 'Error'])"/>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="Result">
     <ul>
      <xsl:for-each select="Message">
        <li>
          <xsl:value-of select="Description" />
        </li>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
    Total Count Error:<xsl:value-of select="count(Message[Type = 'Error'])"/><br />
    Total Count Warning:<xsl:value-of select="count(Message[Type = 'Warning'])"/><br />
    Total Count Information:<xsl:value-of select="count(Message[Type = 'Information'])"/><br />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```